# How to use " " in JSON/VBA instead of null

Tags: json, vba

In formatting  Json we are required Not to show null (But “ “) for any control that has empty value , how do we archive it using VBA code:

```
Private Sub CmdConertJson_Click()
  On Error GoTo Err_Handler
  Dim db As DAO.Database
  Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
  Dim fld As DAO.Field
  Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
  Dim prm As DAO.Parameter
  Dim root As Dictionary
  Set root = New Dictionary
    Dim transaction As Dictionary
    Dim transactions As Collection
    Dim item As Dictionary
    Dim items As Collection
    Dim Tax As Collection
    Dim Z As Integer
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim t As Long
    Set transactions = New Collection
  Set db = CurrentDb
  Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("QryJson")
For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
    prm = Eval(prm.Name)
Next prm
Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot, dbSeeChanges)

Set qdf = Nothing
 rs.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        Set transaction = New Dictionary
        transaction.Add "BuyerName", Me.BuyerName
        transaction.Add "BuyerTaxAccountName", Me.BuyerTaxAccountName
```

For example if Me.BuyerName has EMPTY the json should show “ “  NOT null

```
“BuyerName”, “ ”
“BuyerTaxAccountName”,” ”
```

Comment: Try `transaction.Add "BuyerName", IIf(IsEmpty(Me.BuyerName)," ",Me.BuyerName)`

Comment: It says IsEmpty is invalid property!

Comment: `IsEmpty` is a [built-in Excel and Access function](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/isempty.php). So I'm puzzled. I've tried a sample in both Excel and Access and it works fine. As an alternative, try `transaction.Add "BuyerName", IIf(Me.BuyerName=vbNullString," ",Me.BuyerName)`

Comment: Sorry Peter it was actually my mistake , your concept works for me this way I tried on a small database and it worked , thank you so much you have made a good day for   dict.Add fld.Name, Nz(rs.fields(fld.Name).Value, "")